# How can we limit # of visible items in drop-down select tag in a form?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have the following code which works fine, but i want to limit the number of stores to say 10. So i added a 'size="10" ' attribute to the select tag, but the drop down stops functioning.. Please help!!!

```
<form:select size="10" path="storeid" style="width:200px;" >
                                        <form:options items="${StoreList}" itemValue="storeId"
                                            itemLabel="storeName" />
                                    </form:select>
```

> thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't control how many items are visible in the dropdown list.

In fact you can't even know that the `select` element is shown as a dropdown list at all. If you browse to the page on a mobile phone for example, you will get a completely different way of selecting items, usually a list that covers most or all of the screen.

The HTML standard doesn't dictate how the `select` element is to be shown, so it's entirely up to the browser vendors to choose what they think is the best way to show it.

Comment: :( Any suggestions as to how to improve the look and feel of the page, then? Especially in IE 7..